# Can not load image specified in Qt resource file in Qt5/cmake Project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, qt5

I just started a Qt5 project using cmake as build system. So far this working quite well but I have problems with an icon that I want to load from a qrc file.

Project structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
-- icons/
   CMakeLists.txt
   icons.qrc
   locked.png
-- src/
   CMakeLists.txt
   source files...
```

Top Level CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11) #2.8.11 provides an easy way to build with qt5
project(fluchOmat)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library. This has dependencies on QtGui and QtCore!
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
# Find the QtMultimedia module
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(icons)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

CMakeLists.txt in icons/

```
set(RESOURCE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/icons.qrc
)

qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_ADDED ${RESOURCE})
```

icons.qrc in icons/

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="locked">locked.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

CMakeLists.txt in src/ (important part)

```
add_executable(fluchOmat ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${fluchOmat_FORMS} ${RESOURCES_ADDED})
```

Some sample code

```
QPixmap pm(":/locked.png");
qDebug("Width: " + pm.width());
```

returns nothing, so obviously this didn't work.

There aren't many resources out there for Qt5 and cmake. Can anyone help me with this? Is this a cmake problem? For example I am not sure if qt5_add_resources is at the right location. Is my qrc file wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As your image file has an alias in the resource, does it still fail if you use QPixmap(pm(":/locked"); without the file extension?

Comment: Yes, same problem using the alias.

Comment: Well, the resource file and requesting of the image look fine, so I'd assume the problem is with how cmake is including the resource file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the scoping rules of CMake.  each `add_subdirectory` call creates its own scope.  Variables declared in such a subdirectory aren't automatically populated up to the parent scope.

So the problem is that while `RESOURCE_ADDED` contains a valid path in the scope of icons/CMakeLists.txt, it doesn't in the root CMakeLists.txt and hence it is an empty variable by the time you use it in src/CMakeLists.txt.

To raise the variable up a scope, in icons/CMakeLists.txt you can do:

```
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_ADDED ${RESOURCE})
set(RESOURCE_ADDED ${RESOURCE_ADDED} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

There's another slight problem now though!

While this will contain a valid value in src/CMakeLists.txt, it points to a file which doesn't yet exist.  The `qt5_add_resources` function must apply the [`GENERATED`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_sf%3aGENERATED) source file property to the variable.  This property is not carried forward to the variable set in the parent scope.

Since `add_executable` expects files to exist by default, you'll need to reapply the `GENERATED` property to the variable in the parent scope.  You can do this e.g. in the src/CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
set_source_files_properties(${RESOURCE_ADDED} PROPERTIES GENERATED ON)
add_executable(fluchOmat ... ${RESOURCE_ADDED})
```

I'm not sure if the `qt5_add_resources` adds any other properties - if so, you'd maybe also have to reapply these.

I'd guess the easiest way to avoid this would be to not use `add_subdirectory(icons)`, and instead just move all the Qt-related CMake code to src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(RESOURCE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/icons/icons.qrc)
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_ADDED ${RESOURCE})
add_executable(fluchOmat ... ${RESOURCE_ADDED})
```

Comment: Fraser, thanks for this hint. Very embarrassing asking a question on stackoverflow and having such a stupid typo in my "code". Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: These things happen :-)  I think I've just done the equivalent!  Give me a minute and I'll updated my answer.

Comment: I am sorry to not have answered here for more than a week. Was quite busy. Anyway you where right this was a coping problem. I did it the simple way and added everything needed to src/CMakeLists.txt Had additional problems when using an icon bigger than 16x16 on a QToolButton. So I thought I still have a CMake issue :) But now everything works as expected. Thank you very much!